# Why does a regex that works in Chrome not work in Poltergeist/PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, phantomjs, poltergeist

I have a problem with some javascript intended to parse a link (in order to embed a video player if appropriate). It works fine in when testing manually in Chrome, but when I run an automated test suite in a different browser, it doesn't.

```
var n = childNodes[i];
var html = n.nodeValue;

var urlVimeo0 = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/;
var urlVimeo1 = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)($)/;
var urlVimeo2 = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)(\/)/;
var urlVimeo3 = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)$/,
var urlVimeo4 = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)\//,
var urlVimeo5 = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)/;

// Comments show output when run in Poltergeist/PhantomJS
console.log('"'+html+'"'); // "http://vimeo.com/26278283​"
console.log(html.match(urlVimeo0)); // null
console.log(html.match(urlVimeo1)); // null
console.log(html.match(urlVimeo2)); // null
console.log(html.match(urlVimeo3)); // null
console.log(html.match(urlVimeo4)); // null
console.log(html.match(urlVimeo5)); // http://vimeo.com/26278283,,26278283

// Output in Chrome (same order)
// "http://vimeo.com/26278283" 
// ["http://vimeo.com/26278283", undefined, "26278283", "", index: 0, input: "http://vimeo.com/26278283"] 
// ["http://vimeo.com/26278283", undefined, "26278283", "", index: 0, input: "http://vimeo.com/26278283"] 
// null 
// ["http://vimeo.com/26278283", undefined, "26278283", index: 0, input: "http://vimeo.com/26278283"] 
// null
// ["http://vimeo.com/26278283", undefined, "26278283", index: 0, input: "http://vimeo.com/26278283"]
```

The original (`urlVimeo0`) works in Chrome, but when I run this as part of a test suite using Poltergeist, nothing works when there's anything after the bit matching the digits. Both are webkit based, so I have no idea why the dollar/slash is causing a failure.

Comment: Seems like poltergeist has a problem matching `$` against the end of the string. What does `console.log("foo".match(/foo$/))` show?

Comment: Try: `/http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)(.*)$/`

Comment: That works. Weird. What could be stuck onto the end that doesn't show up when I log the string?

Comment: There's something invisible in the nodeValue. What is that showing in the result array after `"26278283"`

Comment: You're right, but I can't work out how to view it. Copy/paste to my IDE from the console shows nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Poltergeist/PhantomJS, so can't help you there.

Comment: Got it: `console.log('"'+ encodeURI(html)+'"'); \\ "http://vimeo.com/26278283%E2%80%8B"`

Comment: Zero width space character. Must be an artifact of the way I'm triggering the link being inserted into a text editor using jQuery for the test. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** escape your dollar signs `/foo\$/`, and PhantomJS uses a really old version of Webkit with different support for regex syntax than Chrome.

--

You have two potential problems.

The first is your usage of `$`; be aware that in a regular expression it means the end of the string (and `^` means the beginning of the string). So `/foo$/` will match `"a_foo"` but will *not* match `"foo_a"`, and will not match `"foo$"` either.

If you're actually trying to match a dollar sign in your string you need to escape it: `/foo\$/`.

The second problem is that while PhantomJS (which Poltergeist uses under the hood) *is* based on Webkit, it's an ancient, shitty, forked version of Webkit only used by PhantomJS, and it lacks a lot of modern features including various extensions to regular expression syntax. So you will see some differences between Chrome's interpretation of your regexes and PhantomJS's.

If you want to dig into the available browser compatibility tables/specifications, you could start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Specifications. Anything that's available in the ECMAScript 3 spec is probably available in PhantomJS. Anything that comes after is suspect.